# How is BizTalk's support for X12N standards?

Tags: biztalk

If you're using a BizTalk solution for any X12N EDI transactions, how well has its support for 270/271, 276/277 etc. worked for 4010 and/or 5010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, BizTalk can support 4010 and 5010 document parsing/disassembly for several transaction sets. Schemas are provided for 270/271, 276/277, 278, 820, 834, 835, and 837P/I/D formats.

In our organization we use BizTalk to process requests for nearly all of those transactions mentioned above. Most transactions are batched. We also published a web service that handles 270/271 request/response in real-time.

Keep in mind that BizTalk is a framework for building applications. Out of the box it doesn't really do much of anything useful. You have to build all of your business logic.

Comment: Technically schemas are provided for all X12 transactions, just in a different area than the Healthcare specific transactions.  It also supports all of the base messaging constructs such as 997 & 999.